# Assigning value to concatenated characters python

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I am trying to work on a problem where it would be convenient to assign values to a variable , which itself would be the concatenation of two strings. Obviously, I am getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: can\'t assign to operator
```

Part of the code I am trying to make it work:

```
char1 = 'a'
char2 = 'b'

char1+char2 = [element1,element2]
```

I am trying to assign a list to a new variable called ab . I apologize for my naivety. Suggestions please?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead?

Comment: Okay, I think I oversimplified my problem. I would like to create a list with the variable ab. This is not possible with dictionary. I should edit my question, I guess.

Comment: This is generally not something you want to do. It would be more useful to say what problem you want to solve, to get recommendations as to how those kinds of problems are usually approached in Python.

Comment: `ab = 'newstring'` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do what you ask but it is not recommended.  Instead, use a dictionary to hold variables whose names you create on the fly:

```
mydict = {}
char1 = 'a'
char2 = 'b'

mydict[char1+char2] = [1, 2]
print(mydict)
```

This results in:

```
{'ab': [1, 2]}
```

As you can see, the dictionary now has a key `ab` with your value assigned.  When you want to access this variable, use `mydict['ab']`.

#### Yet another method

It is also possible to assign to class instances attributes with names created on the fly.  For example:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
setattr(a, char1+char2, [3, 4])
print(a.ab)
```

This will print:

```
[3, 4]
```

Attributes can also be accessed by a name constructed on the fly:

```
print(getattr(a, char1+char2))
```

which prints:

```
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Solves the problem. I didn't realize that lists can be used as values in a key:value pair in a dictionary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way I can see of doing it:

```
>>> c1 = 'a'
>>> c2 = 'b'
>>> vars = {}
>>> vars[c1+c2] = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print vars['ab']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ooops ... sorry John1024 you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just have your logic flipped on the third variable. Build your list of variables, and then assign a new variable to concatenate that list.
Like this:

```
char1 = ('a')
char2 = ('b')

char3 = char1 + char2

print char3
```